# Where does Eclipse print messages that it outputs within an annotation processor?

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations

Where does [Eclipse Juno](http://www.eclipse.org/juno/) print the messages that the following annotation processor, `ComplexityProcessor`, outputs when it compiles class `SimpleAnnotationTest`?  After compilation, I expect to see the messages in the Console pane, but it is empty.

```
public @interface Complexity
{
    public enum Level
    {
        VERY_SIMPLE,
        SIMPLE,
        MEDIUM,
        COMPLEX,
        VERY_COMPLEX;
    }

    Level value() default Level.MEDIUM;
}

@SupportedAnnotationTypes("com.intelerad.annotations.Complexity")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_6)
public class ComplexityProcessor extends AbstractProcessor
{
    @Override
    public boolean process( final Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
                            final RoundEnvironment environment )
    {
        for ( final Element element : environment.getElementsAnnotatedWith( Complexity.class ) )
        {
            final Complexity complexity = element.getAnnotation( Complexity.class );
            String message =
                "Annotation found in " + element.getSimpleName() + " with complexity " +
                complexity.value();

            // Where does Eclipse print this message?
            processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage( Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE, message );
        }
        return true;
    }
}

@Complexity(Level.VERY_SIMPLE)
public class SimpleAnnotationTest
{
    @Complexity()
    public void theMethod()
    {
        System.out.println( "console output" );
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is `processingEnv`? Or `processingEnv.messager`? Do you have it's source?

Comment: `processingEnv` is a member of `javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor` and is of type `ProcessingEnvironment`.  `messager` is a `Messager` in `javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment`.  The javac `Messager` outputs messages to the console, so I mistekenly expected `Messager` in Eclipse to do the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the output in the Eclipse `.metadata/.log`:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core 1 1 2013-01-23 16:45:35.102
!MESSAGE Annotation found in SimpleAnnotationTest with complexity VERY_SIMPLE

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core 1 1 2013-01-23 16:45:35.102
!MESSAGE Annotation found in theMethod with complexity MEDIUM
```

Comment: Can we have the processor log at console to have proper monitoring??